# Entity Framework Database first 1 to 0..1 with designer

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to model the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[expression] (
    CONSTRAINT [PK_expression] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExpressionId] ASC),
    [ExpressionId]     INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [LeftOperatorId]   INT NULL UNIQUE,
    [RightOperatorId]  INT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_expression_leftoperator] FOREIGN KEY ([LeftOperatorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[expression] ([ExpressionId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_expression_rightoperator] FOREIGN KEY ([RightOperatorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[expression] ([ExpressionId])
);
```

When I model this using the EF6 designer I get a 1:many relationship, whereas I would like it to be a 0..1:1 relationship (e.g. the LeftOperator Id can be either NULL or point to an ExpressionId.

When I change this to a 1:0..1 relationship within the designer it fails to regenerate any of the underlying classes! The compiler also comes up with the following error:

Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

I have found one answer from Microsoft detailing how to make changes to the underlying XML which sounds like a really, really crap way of doing things... has anyone solved how to do this with the designer?

Comment: It *is* a 1-0..n association. You may have business logic that ensures that there will always be max 1 record referring to `Left/RightOperatorId`, but as for the db model there can be any. For a real 1-0..1 association the dependent must have a primary key that also is the foreign key to the principal. But that won't work with this kind of double linked list. You'll have to settle with one-to-many.

Comment: That's the conclusion that I came to... thanks for confirming it.